# NDVI_Image: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'B5_median' did not match any bands

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
//load a image from image collection and clip ROI from image collection through median
var dataset= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA')
    .filterDate('2012-05-01','2012-09-30')
    .filterBounds(table)
    .sort('CLOUD COVER')

//print(Collection);


var medianimage= dataset.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
print(medianimage)
var viz ={
  bands:['B7_median','B5_median','B3_median'],
  min:0,
  max:0.4,
};

Map.addLayer(medianimage, viz, 'l8median_image')
Map.addLayer(medianimage.clip(table), viz, 'l8medianordos_image')
//Map.addLayer(table)

//select and rename bands
var image= medianimage.select(['B5_median','B4_median','B3_median','B2_median'],
                              ['nir','red','green','blue']);
var nir=image.select('nir');
var red=image.select('red');
var green=image.select('green');
var blue=image.select('blue');

/* compute the NDVI
NDVI = (NIR - RED)/(NIR + RED)*/
var ndvi= nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');
//automatic NDVI and NDWI

var ndvi= image.normalizedDifference(['nir','red']);
var ndwi=image.normalizedDifference(['green','nir']);

//Display NDVI Result

var ndviParams = {min:-1, max:1, palette:['blue','white','green']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi.clip(table), ndviParams, 'NDVI_Image');

//Display NDWI Result
var ndwiParams = {min:-1, max:1, palette:['blue','white','green']};
Map.addLayer(ndwi.clip(table), ndwiParams, 'NDWI_Image');

//Compute and display Enhanced Vegetation Index(EVI)
// EVI= 2.5*((NIR - RED)/ (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))

var evi= image.expression(
  '2.5*((NIR - RED)/ (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))',{
    NIR:image.select('nir'),
    RED:image.select('red'),
    BLUE:image.select('blue')
  });
var eviParams = {min:-1, max:1, palette:['blue','white','green']};
Map.addLayer(evi.clip(table), eviParams, 'EVI_Image');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ndvi,
  region:table,
  description:'NDVI_table',
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:1e10,
  });
  
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ndwi,
  region:table,
  description:'NDWI_table',
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:1e10,
  });
  
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image:evi,
  region:table,
  description:'EVI_table',
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:1e10,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no images in your collection.  Landsat 8 didn't launch until 2013, so filtering to images in 2012 results in 0 images.